# Treadmill using strange power conversion

Tags: thermodynamics, work, power

Yesterday, while on a treadmill I saw a power reading of 250 watts next to a calories /hour of ~1000. The established conversion rate of 1 watt = .860 kcal/hour would imply an hourly rate of 215 kcal, so what explains this disparity? Does this have to do with some inefficiency of the human body in converting calories from food to mechanical energy?

Comment: Was the power reading from the motor that ran the treadmill? That would be different from the power of the person walking on it.

Comment: No, it was supposed to be a measure of my power

Comment: So, clearly, it is not a simple physics question. It may be biophysics (based on body efficiency), marketing (based on who knows what), or a programming error.